# Unable to align items within draggablescrollablesheet when extending body behind appbar

Tags: flutter, stack, draggable

We have a screen that is a stack with a google map at tap, and a draggablescrollablesheet at the bottom which is going to show a list that relates to the map. but the problem is the list items are being pushed down and we aren't sure why this is happening

[image]

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      extendBody: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        centerTitle: false,
        title: Text(
          "$_currentAddress (~${_distance.round()} km)",
          overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleMedium,
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              showFiltersDialog();
            },
            icon: const Icon(LucideIcons.filter),
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) {
                    return Notifications(
                      userId: widget.currentUserId,
                    );
                  },
                ),
              );
            },
            icon: const Icon(LucideIcons.bell),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
              return SizedBox(
                height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.8,
                child: GoogleMap(
                  buildingsEnabled: false,
                  myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
                  zoomGesturesEnabled: true,
                  zoomControlsEnabled: false,
                  minMaxZoomPreference: const MinMaxZoomPreference(0, 13),
                  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                    _controller.complete(controller);
                    controller
                        .setMapStyle(_mapStyle); // Apply the loaded map style
                  },
                  onCameraMove: (CameraPosition position) {
                    _updateTasksOnMapMove(position.target);
                  },
                  initialCameraPosition: _initialPosition,
                  markers: _markers, // Add the markers to the GoogleMap widget
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          DraggableScrollableSheet(
            initialChildSize: 0.4,
            minChildSize: 0.25,
            maxChildSize: 1,
            snapSizes: const [0.25, 0.6, 1],
            snap: true,
            builder: (BuildContext context, scrollSheetController) {
              return Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onPrimary,
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(32.0),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(32.0),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 12.0),
                      child: Center(
                        child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icons/handle.svg'),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: _buildDisplayTasks(context, scrollSheetController),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```